# scatter plot in blank when adding marker size

Tags: python

following tipical example to learn how matplotlib works, I found one thing that I don't know how to solve.

Describing the dataframe:

[image: Describing the dataframe:]

then when I create the plot without size I can see the data:

```js
    # Change the line plot below to a scatter plot
    plt.scatter(gdp_cap, life_exp)
    
    # Put the x-axis on a logarithmic scale
    plt.xscale('log')
    
    # Show plot
    plt.show()
```

[image: plot without datapoints size]

but the point is when I try to add the size, the data points in the plot dissapears:

```js
    # Scatter plot
    plt.scatter(x = gdp_cap, y = life_exp, s = np.array(pop) * 2)
    
    # Previous customizations
    plt.xscale('log') 
    
    
    # Show the plot
    plt.show()
```

[image: plot with datapoints size]

Comment: Point size of 31889923*2 (if I interpret right that your pop is population size) is going to be HUGE (thus you're obviously filling up the axis). Try to decrease these values (I'd suggest division by 10 000 000 first, adjust as fit).

Comment: you were right @dm2 no decreasing the population I can see the scatter plot data.thx